# AVPlayer not playing local mp4

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I am trying to use an `AVPlayer` to play a video that has been recorded in my app. However, the player won't play the video. I know for a fact that this is a properly recorded mp4 file, because I can take it and play it on my Mac just fine. Here's the setup for the player:

```
let documents = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!
let URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "tempVideo", relativeToURL: documentsDirectory)
let asset = AVAsset(URL: URL)
let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

//videoPlayer is a property on the view controller being used
videoPlayer = AVPlayer()

//videoPlayerLayer is a property on the view controller being used
videoPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: videoPlayer)
videoPlayerLayer.frame.size = view.frame.size
videoPlayerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

view.layer.addSublayer(videoPlayerLayer!)

//wait 5 seconds

videoPlayer.play()
```

I know for sure that the `videoPlayer` is, in fact, ready to play, because I've checked its `status` property. I also know that `videoPlayerLayer` has properly been added to `view.layer` because its visible and takes up the whole screen. When I call `videoPlayer.play()`, the music playing on the device stops, but `videoPlayerLayer` doesn't show anything.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance for the help!

**EDIT**: I forgot to show that `videoPlayerLayer` is indeed connected to `videoPlayer`, I have updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: I think you need to specify the format of the video too like "tempVideo.mp4".

Comment: Did you assigned the item to AVPlayer and player to player layer ? I couldn't find that code in  your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer was given by @Dershowitz123, but he or she left it in a comment so I can't mark it as correct. The solution was to change the URL to include the `.mp4` extension. Thank you for your help.